# python: modifying label behavior in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
plt.rc('axes', grid=True)
plt.rc('grid', color='0.75', linestyle='-', linewidth=0.5)

textsize = 9
left, width = 0.1, 0.8
rect1 = [left, 0.7, width, 0.2]

fig = plt.figure(facecolor='white')
axescolor  = '#f6f6f6'  # the axes background color

ax1 = fig.add_axes(rect1, axisbg=axescolor)  #left, bottom, width, height

### plot the relative strength indicator

rsi = RSI(GOOG,20) #rsi[0] is list of float, rsi[1] is list of datetime objects
rsiValues = rsi[0]
rsiDate = rsi[1]
ticker = 'GOOG'
fillcolor = 'darkgoldenrod'

ax1.plot(rsiDate, rsiValues, 'kx') #, fmt='bo', tz=None, xdate=True, ydate=False,color=fillcolor)
ax1.axhline(70, color=fillcolor)
ax1.axhline(30, color=fillcolor)
#ax1.fill_between(rsiDate, rsiValues, 70, where=(rsiValues>=70),facecolor=fillcolor,   edgecolor=fillcolor)
#ax1.fill_between(rsiDate, rsiValues, 30, where=(rsiValues<=30), facecolor=fillcolor, edgecolor=fillcolor)
ax1.text(0.6, 0.9, '>70 = overbought', va='top', transform=ax1.transAxes, fontsize=textsize)
ax1.text(0.6, 0.1, '<30 = oversold', transform=ax1.transAxes, fontsize=textsize)
ax1.set_ylim(0, 100)
ax1.set_yticks([30,70])
ax1.set_xticks(rsiDate,minor = True)

#just want day date
tickLabels = []
for items in rsiDate:
    tickLabels.append(items.day) 

ax1.set_xticklabels(tickLabels, rotation = 45,minor = True)
ax1.text(0.025, 0.95, 'RSI (20)', va='top', transform=ax1.transAxes, fontsize=textsize)
ax1.set_title('%s daily'%ticker)

plt.show()
```

If I comment out "minor = True"

```
ax1.set_xticklabels(tickLabels, rotation = 45)#,minor = True)
```

the day dates for major tick labels shows correctly (only day date shows), but if I uncomment it (as it is) all tick labels show, but with added 'month-day-year' labels on major ticks. I am trying to get only day dates on all ticks (minor included) without any 'month-day-year' labels.

Answer (score 0):

```
ax1.tick_params(which='major', axis = 'x', labelbottom = 'off')
```

Adding this line of code works.